# I am "friends" with John, then John is "x" to me

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for a word that defines the direction of friendship between two people.

For example, when I say "I am friends with John" or "John is my friend". How would I describe the same thing, but from John's perspective.

The reason I ask is that I am trying to write a database schema that uses words to define the direction of friendships. One possible option is to use two phrases "friend with" and "friends to". So that I could describe who John is friends with from both directions.

If this doesn't make any sense, sorry ;)

Comment: Friendship is a symmetric relation. So when X is Y's friend, Y is X's friend as well.

Comment: To add to what @Gigili said, *like* is the potentially non-symmetric relation.  X *likes* Y but Y does not like X. X might want Y to be their friend but they are not friends unless X and Y like each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most systems use "friend" only for symmetric relationships.  Someone in an asymmetric relationship is typically a "fan" or a "follower" (sometimes a "subscriber" or a "watcher").